# Find specific divs on page and remove before taking screenshot with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a node/puppeteer script that visits a page, finds a specific div with a class, and takes a screenshot of the div. However, there are elements/nodes on the page that I'd like to delete before capturing the screenshot since they are interfering with the image, but can't seem to find the documentation on how to do so.

This is what I have so far, but can't figure out when or how to delete a given div with a specific class `.ce45` for instance:

```
await page.setViewport({
    width: 1368,
    height: 768
});
await page.waitForSelector(`.${url.id.toLowerCase()}`).then(() => console.log('scraped', url.id.toLowerCase()));        
const component = await page.$(`.${url.id.toLowerCase()}`);     
const bounding_box = await component.boundingBox();  
await component.screenshot({
   path: `./${url.id.toLowerCase()}.png`,
   clip: {
      x: bounding_box.x,
      y: bounding_box.y,
        width: Math.min(bounding_box.width, page.viewport().width),
        height: Math.min(bounding_box.height, page.viewport().height),
   }
});
```

I have tried:

```
await page.evaluate((sel) => {
  let div_selector_to_remove = ['.ce45', '.d20', '.cc27'];
  for(sel of div_selector_to_remove){
     document.querySelector(`${sel}`).remove();
  }
});
```

but get the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')`

Comment: What page is this? It's hard to help without seeing it and having a runnable [mcve] to play with. Not the problem, but `for(sel` should be `for (cosnt sel` -- always use `const` or you'll create a global. Otherwise, your selector removal code seems fine, so there's probably some page-specific behavior preventing it from working. Could be pretty much anything--an iframe, a shadow dom, a bad selector, JS removing the element just before you do. Who knows.

Comment: Are you trying to actually "delete" these `div`s (as in, remove them permanently from the page unless it refreshed) or are you merely trying to hide them visually until the screenshot is taken? That being said, the error you are getting is because `querySelector(\`${sel}\`)` isn't returning an element from the page and is returning `null`. Figure out the problem there. Can't do it without the HTML too.

Comment: Easy way to test this is comment out the line with the `remove` method and put `console.log(querySelector(\`${sel}\`))` in that loop and see what it returns. I'm pretty sure you'll get at least one `null` response. Then I would check the HTML and see if the one(s) that are null have some typo or something with the class name.

Comment: Above console.log line should obviously be `console.log(document.querySelector(\`${sel}\`))`

Comment: @StephenMIrving - I am trying to remove the elements from the page, as they are sitting on top of the id's I'm trying to screenshot. I can run the snippet ```let div_selector_to_remove = ['.cb27', '.ochat_slideout'];
            for(const sel of div_selector_to_remove){
               document.querySelector(sel).remove();
            }``` in the console, and see that the elements are being removed, but getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove')` when running the snipped in my nodejs file with puppeteer.

Comment: Sounds like your nodejs file is not correctly pointing to the DOM of the page. The error is because `querySelector` is returning `null` which obviously has no `remove` method. Can't help any more than that without seeing more of how the project is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it will only remove the first for each selector (and throw error when it's not there).

Try:

```
page.$$eval('.ce45,.d20,.cc27', els => els.map(el => el.remove()))
```